# jekyll serve -w is not working

Tags: python, jekyll

I just downloaded Jekyll to test out the "jekyll serve --watch" function on sass compiling, but it is not working for me. "jekyll serve" doesn't watch anything to poll for sass changes. Is anyone having the same issue?

I have jekyll 3.0.1, Python 2.7.5, Node 0.10.32, Sass 3.4.19, Compass 0.12.2 installed.

```
$ gem install jekyll
$ jekyll new my-awesome-site
$ cd my-awesome-site
/my-awesome-site $ jekyll serve
```

My "_config.yml" setting:

```
# General settings
highlighter: pygments
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: :compressed
```

Note: I tried "jekyll serve", "jekyll serve -w", and "jekyll serve --watch", none work.

Comment: What is the output of a `jekyll serve --trace` ?

Comment: Configuration file: /Users/Sites/styleguide/_config.yml  
Source: /Users/Sites/styleguide  
Destination: /Users/Sites/styleguide/_site  
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental  
Generating...  
                    done in 2.485 seconds.  
Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/Sites/styleguide'  
Configuration file: /Users/Sites/styleguide/_config.yml  
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/   
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.

Comment: I see compass in your versions list. Did you use a compass based framework ? Did you have a github repository ?

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/joannaho/jekyll-test.

Comment: So, no change in the console like `Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2015-12-03 18:09:50 ...done in 0.347705382 seconds.` when saving a file in  `_sass/` ? Here it regenerates two times (opened a bug on jekyll for this https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4213). See my response below.

Answer (score 2):

I've explored your code. I was unable to reproduce, but it seems that there is a [bug in Jekyll scss regeneration](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4213).

My advice is to switch to a stable version of Jekyll.

1 - Create a `Gemfile` at the root of your jekyll site, containing :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

This will help setup a Github pages environment, which is known to be stable.

2 - Install bundler

```
gem install bundle
```

3 - Install stable gems

```
bundle install
```

4 - Run your Jekull

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Would you have Sass installed locally? If you do, try running sass watch and also `bundle exec jekyll serve safe --watch` (following David's answer)... Should work, as sass will get the css properly compiled and bundle will exec jekyll to build your site on safe mode (as GitHub pages will).